# Changed userid on Mac OS X 10.7 and am now missing login icon for my user

Tags: mac, osx-lion, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No user list in the login screen after changing the user ID](https://superuser.com/questions/318835/no-user-list-in-the-login-screen-after-changing-the-user-id)

I changed my userid on my new MBP (10.7) to match the NFS id I have with my NAS and my mac mini (from  default 501 to 1000) and now my picture no longer shows up on the login screen.  I have the same problem with the mini (10.6) and never bothered to fix it.  Is there a way to control which accounts show up in the login screen?

Comment: What did you do to change the UID?

Comment: http://www.inteller.net/notes/change-user-id-on-snow-leopard